# using @Html.Raw in javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have following line of code inside my js function saved as separate js file

```
 $('#Page').val(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.MyFormats));
```

on page loading inside firebug console I'm getting following error

> SyntaxError: illegal character

with pointer to `@` inside `@Html.Raw...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Razor code is not parsed in external files. You need to assign the value of `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.MyFormats)` to a javascript variable in the main view and pass it to your external script (for example, assign it to a global variable and then use `$('#Page').val(myFormats);`)